# have you ever been picked up at a metro station ? or has someone ever asked you in metro?

Tags: grammar

What's the correct English for asking this question or variants of this question?
According to me, i think asking " have you ever been got asked out in a metro" would be grammatically wrong. or not?
confused 
Please help.